# How to set response header in JAX-RS so that Chinese chars are displayed properly within the custom generated file

Tags: java, rest, character-encoding, response, jax-rs

How would I properly generate a "javax.ws.rs.core.Response" (to be returned) that supports Chinese character encoding within an Excel file?

To clarify, i have a file (CSV excel) which contains some Chinese content, and I need to return a javax response which then displays the Chinese characters in the document properly (on the client side).

Currently I'm doing the following:

```
return Response.status( 200 )
        .header( "content-disposition", 
                 "attachment;filename=SampleCSV.csv;charset=Unicode" )
        .entity( result )
        .build();
```

but when this response is built and returned to the client side (and a popup screen is displayed asking to download the file), the Chinese content of the excel file is gobbly gooed.

Any suggestion will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [RFC](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2183) that defines the content-disposition header doesn't mention a charset clause

Try also adding a proper content-type header to the response:

```
.header("Content-Type", "text/csv; charset=utf-8")
```

Be sure to use utf-8, and not unicode. If that works, then you can remove the `charset` clause from the content-disposition header.

Answer (score 3):

You specify `charset=Unicode`, which is not valid because Unicode is not a single encoding. It's a character set with a family of encodings. UTF-8 and UTF-16 are commonly-used encodings.

You can control the response header, to affect how the browser/client interprets the response, using the `@Produces` annotation. I've seen different opinions about whether this works:

- ["I've tried @Produces("text/html; charset=UTF-8") but that was ignored and only text/html was send with the HTTP header"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3431996/how-to-set-the-charset-with-jax-rs)
- ["It is also possible to use ResponseBuilder.header(...) method to set the content type with the charset."](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7249885/648162)
- [The @Produces annotation sends the corrects charset in the header, but doesn't change the encoding of the body](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8233874/character-encoding-responses-with-resteasy-jax-rs)
- ["@Produces("text/html; charset=UTF-8") works with current versions of the reference implementation Jersey."](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3431996/how-to-set-the-charset-with-jax-rs#comment9671241_3431996)
- It worked for me in Jersey 1.12.

I'm fairly certain that this only changes the encoding **declared** in the response headers; it doesn't change the encoding that's **actually used** to convert the response string into bytes to send over the network. These two must match, otherwise the browser/client will misinterpret the response, because it believes that you used a different encoding than you actually did.

If you return a java.lang.String object, JAx-RS uses a system default encoding to convert it to a byte stream. If the JAX-RS server is running on Unix this is UTF-8, which usually works well, but on Windows it's something weird that doesn't.

Therefore you should force it to use a specific encoding, by wrapping the result object in an `OutputStreamWriter` that specifies the encoding. This prevents JAX-RS from using the default conversion.

To be specific, if `result` is a java.lang.String object in your code, you may need to create an OutputStreamWriter around it that specifies an encoding, such as UTF-8, to affect byte stream that JAX-RS writes to the network. I haven't tested this code, but it might work:

```
.entity(new OutputStreamWriter(result, "UTF-8"))
```

I had this [problem with Tika](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/TIKA-912), which sends a `StreamingOutput` instead of a `Response`, and constructs it with a default `OutputStreamWriter`, which uses the system's default encoding instead of something predictable.

I [modified Tika](https://issues.apache.org/jira/secure/attachment/12525681/TikaResource-utf8-response.patch) to specify the encoding when constructing the `OutputStreamWriter`, and added a `charset` to the `@Produces` annotation, and that fixed it for me.